# What is the cleanest and easiest way to share custom RSpec matchers across multiple ruby/rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

I'm currently using Git to manage all my projects and would like to know if there's a convention associated with my question. I'm currently weighing the pros and cons of collecting the code into a gem or using Git submodules.

Answer (score 0):

i think you better use the gem way, it has no cons compared to git submodules (you can transform any git repository to gem easily), but it's much more easier to manage dependencies when you use gems